# Swift 3.0: "objc_setAssociatedObject" issue

Tags: ios, objective-c-runtime, swift3

```
import UIKit
import ObjectiveC

var SubRowObjectKey: String = "subRow"
extension IndexPath {

    var subRow: Int {
        get {
            let subRowObj = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &SubRowObjectKey)
        
            if subRowObj != nil {
                return (subRowObj as! Int)
            }
        
            return 0
        }
        set {
            let subRowObj = (newValue as NSInteger)
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &SubRowObjectKey, subRowObj, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
        
        }
    }

    static func indexPathForSubRow(_ subRow: NSInteger, inRow row: NSInteger, inSection section: NSInteger) -> IndexPath {
    
        var indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
        indexPath.subRow = (subRow as Int)
        print(subRow)
        print(indexPath.subRow)
        return indexPath
    }
}

let indexPath = IndexPath.indexPathForSubRow(5, inRow: 1, inSection: 2)
print(indexPath.subRow)
```

[image]

- In static func indexPathForSubRow -> 'subRow' Count = 5 (line no: 30 in attached image)
- But after assigning subRow to indexPath.subRow, 'indexPath.subRow' count = 0 instead of 5 (line no 29 & 31 in attached image)
- Tested in Xcode version 8.2.1 & Swift 3.0

  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please post actual code into your question. It is easier to read and reference.

Comment: @rmaddy Code posted

Comment: FYI - there is no need to use associated objects for this. `IndexPath` already supports any number of indexes. `row` and `section` are just convenience properties for accessing the values at indexes 0 and 1. Simply store your `subRow` at index 2 of the index path.

Answer (score 3):

`IndexPath` is a struct, which don't support associated objects. 
You can easily check it in the setter by directly trying to read back the set object:

```
set {
    let subRowObj = (newValue as NSInteger)
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &SubRowObjectKey, subRowObj, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
    let subRowObj2 = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &SubRowObjectKey)
    print(subRowObj2 ?? "nil") // prints "nil"
}
```

Even if the code in the setter *would have worked*, the whole construct still doesn't hold: Since structs are copied when *transferred / assigned* (at least when modified via *copy on write* mechanism), your associated objects won't be included in that copy, so you'll lose that information anyhow, sooner or later.

Nevertheless, instead of extending `IndexPath` you *could* extend `NSIndexPath` which then works fine -- but I guess this is not what you want, because you want to influence the IndexPath that you get from a table view...

Answer (score 0):

Based on maddy's answer this is my IndexPath extension that adds a subRow property.

```
extension IndexPath {

    init(subRow: Int, row: Int, section: Int) {
        self.init(indexes: [IndexPath.Element(section), IndexPath.Element(row), IndexPath.Element(subRow)])
    }

    var subRow: Int {
        get { return self[index(at: 2)] }
        set { self[index(at: 2)] = newValue }
    }

    var row: Int {
        get { return self[index(at: 1)] }
        set { self[index(at: 1)] = newValue }
    }

    var section: Int {
        get { return self[index(at: 0)] }
        set { self[index(at: 0)] = newValue }
    }

    private func index(at idx: Int) -> IndexPath.Index {
        return self.startIndex.advanced(by: idx)
    }

}
```